# WSS 3.0 to Sharepoint Foundation 2010: Potential Upgrade Blocking Issues

Tags: wss-3.0, upgrade

I am running the pre upgrade checklist for WSS 3.0, and I get the following Potential Upgrade Blocking Issues:
[image]

I have run the [Sharepoint Cleanup Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) it found some invalid things and we removed those.

I also logged onto the sharepoint site and removed the webparts that reference these files, but I am still getting the error.

How can I remove these webparts or file references entirely as I am sure we do not use them.

Comment: did you uninstall the features or just delete the files on the server?

Comment: There was no un-install option under the webpart Edit Item page, only Delete. So they were deleted. as for a Windows level uninstall, I am unsure how they go there in the first place, we  really have not  added any custom anything to WSS, just install and go.

Comment: you can go on central admin and from system settings and manager farm solutions...see if anything listed their.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976218).

If missing files are listed, you can do one of the following:

1. Install the missing files on the server before you perform an
   in-place upgrade.
2. Build a new farm with the listed files installed.
3. Remove the content that references the missing files.

Comment: I read that, the problem is: I don't know how or where they were installed, so I cannot re-install. I do not want, nor do i have the resources to build a new farm, and I have no idea how to find references to the content other than the places I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: from central admin, manage farm solutions if anything listed their

Comment: I was just trying to get there, I am having trouble finding manage farm solutions, I have Share Point site management. . I am googling now to see if I can find it!

Comment: found Manage Farm Features, nothing there

Comment: try this link and specially step 8.http://blog.uvm.edu/jgm/2010/08/25/preparing-the-sharepoint-2007wss3-database-for-upgrade/

Comment: Close! this is almost what I need, but this entire article is base don the assumption that my missing files are Meeting Workspace template when Mine are Contoso and a Report Viewer. I think I need to find the name as seen on line 4 of the referenced script Object { $_.GetType().FullName -ne "System.Reflection.Assembly" }

Comment: No, you logic will change at #14, where he checking which template it is.

Comment: I just realized that myself, I am trying again with variations of my file name trying to come up with a match, can't seem to get any matches however.

Comment: another way create a web part and add it.here is the webpart i believe which is missing......http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/07/02/step-by-step-creating-connected-sharepoint-web-parts-using-iwebpartfield-interface-and-using-editor-part-and-user-controls.aspx

Comment: also try this one.....http://www.allthefixes.com/moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010-upgrade-missing-server-file-or-server-configuration-issues/.........i think this should work

Comment: so this from all the fixes looks like it would help http://www.allthefixes.com/moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010-upgrade-missing-server-file-or-server-configuration-issues/ however I had already manually deleted the web parts from the site, and now cannot complete the step where it tells me which site / page contains the webpart.  Thanks for all your help so far Waqas

Comment: two things, either try to re install it( one of link give you the code) or if nothing then try to upgrade and see if it blocks it...do you have any other farm where this webpart exist...may be copy from their

Comment: No other farms, Also Restored and old version of the database, still unable to look up the web parts base don this article, they apparently just don't exist. I will try to reinstall, and upgrade and see what happens. thanks again